# TypeScript parseFloat not working

Tags: typescript

What is wrong with this ?  The parseFloat returns only the 0 and yet in string it's "0.9"

[image]

Comment: Could you show your actual .js file that was created and not the typescript one?

Comment: I suspect the problem is not `parseFloat`. Ideally, you need to give us a minimal working example of the problem so we can recreate your issue (i.e. place a fully working demo of the problem in your question). I have tested `var opacity = "0.9"; var parsed = parseFloat(opacity); alert(parsed);` and it works as expected, so your problem lies elsewhere.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yeah, looks like I wasn't coding right in the interval and this was giving wrong results so I changed the code in order to have a better logic and now it works.  Here's the result code :

```
var FaderElement = (function () {
function FaderElement() {
}
FaderElement.prototype.FadeOutElement = function (id, Min) {
    var Element = document.getElementById(id);
    var currentOpacity;
    clearInterval(this._intervalin);
    this._intervalout = setInterval(function () {
        currentOpacity = parseFloat(Element.currentStyle.opacity);
        if (currentOpacity > Min) {
            currentOpacity -= 0.1;
            Element.style.opacity = currentOpacity.toString();
        }
        else {
            clearInterval(this.intervalout);
        }
    }, 33);
};
FaderElement.prototype.FadeInElement = function (id, Max) {
    var Element = document.getElementById(id);
    var currentOpacity;
    clearInterval(this._intervalout);
    this._intervalin = setInterval(function () {
        currentOpacity = parseFloat(Element.currentStyle.opacity);
        if (currentOpacity < Max) {
            currentOpacity += 0.1;
            Element.style.opacity = currentOpacity.toString();
        }
        else {
            clearInterval(this.intervalin);
        }
    }, 33);
};
return FaderElement;
```

})();

Comment: please summarize the changes you made and how you actually solved your problem instead of pasting a large chunk of uncommented code.

Comment: I agree I should have done that 3 years ago but I don't have this code anymore and after 3 years, It's hard to summarize.  Sorry !